# blur while motion in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

How can i apply blur filter to moving text or object.
For example - spinning numbers in slot games - http://clip2net.com/s/5Gpemi .

I can animate, but have no idea how to do bluring:

```
 var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
        period = period + step;
        step = step + 0.01;
        for (i=0; i<=cell_count; i++)
        {
            text[i].setY(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + (field_height - cell_width) + 5);
        }

    }, layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial yet?

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-blur-filter-tutorial/

You can use the `filter` property like so:

```
 darth = new Kinetic.Image({
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   image: imageObj,
   draggable: true,
   filter: Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
   filterRadius: 20
 });
```

Comment: I have tried setting filter properties for Kinetic.Text - without any result. Also, according to documentaion, Animation takes two params - function and layer - so i cant add filter properties.

Comment: Hmm, I was going to suggest using a Tween to tween the filter property (which is normally doable), but it appears that the filter property is only available for images... Not sure about any other ways to get a blur effect going. Maybe you can overlay a **semi-transparent** shape over your text when you need to blur with perhaps an overlaying shadow.